# tshark: capture specific bytes from a packet data (content)

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I have a captured trace (.pcap) file and I want to read the data field of each captured packet in this trace. I can do this using this command:

tshark -r    aa.pcap  -Tfields  -Y "udp" -e data

```
3000ca02f89f0004000115af0000017900.......
```

This command reads all the content in the data field of each packet. My question is that how can I read specific bytes from the data (e.g. the 5th and 6th bytes only)

```
f89f
```

Comment: What language are you using? What kind of variable or destination should this data be saved to?

Comment: I'm trying to do that using 'tshark' command in my terminal. Any kind of destination would be fine for me. Currently, I use '-e data' option which captures all the data field but I want and an option that can capture part of the data field not all of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [`cut`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) available on your system, you could pipe the `tshark` output to it to isolate the characters you desire.  For example:

```
tshark -r aa.pcap -Tfields -Y "udp" -e data | cut -c 9-12
```

You can even test this as follows:

```
echo 3000ca02f89f0004000115af0000017900 | cut -c 9-12
f89f
```

**EDIT**: I adjusted the offsets from 10-13 to 9-12, as that seems to be the correct offsets.  If you quote the characters in the echo command, then you need 10-13, but those aren't the right offsets you need for the tshark output.

Comment: Note: You may actually need `-c 9-12`.  If you test the echo command without the quotes, then 9-12 works.

Comment: Yeah. I realised that when I tested it.